# Can't break blocks when I change my gamemode back to survival

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been in survival and then I changed it to lan world so I can use cheats.  all the sudden, when I turn my gamemode back to survival I can't break blocks!!!!
This has been happening for the past few months and I want to fix my world.  I do not like when this happens to me because then I can't play my own survival/hardcore game.  How do I change this random glitch in my world back to normal?

Comment: What command do you type to change back to survival?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe when you change it to survival, it changes it to Adventure Mode.  If you don't know what that it, its when you are in survival, but you can't break blocks without the correct tool. i.e - you have to use an ax to chop wood, pickaxe for stone. etc

With cheats, use the command  **/gamemode 0**  to change it to regular survival.

Hope it helps